# How to add a NFC app to "Apps I Trust"?

Tags: 8.1, nfc

I'm using the payments app [SEQR](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=7c25ac1c-dfb7-4cd5-b040-fdeef6ab09a8). It is NFC enabled and I'd like to pay for my cheese burger at McDonalds simply by touching the NFC sticker but it's a little bit hard right now since I ned to unlock the phone and also tap *accept*.

In 8.1, apps can be added to the list **Apps I trust** in the settings for NFC. But, I can't find a way to add the SEQR app to that list even though I've used it's NFC functionality.

How do I add an app to the **Apps I trust** list?

Answer (score 2):

You need to Tap your phone to the NFC enabled device or sticker with your app. Once you do this you need to tap your phone to the NFC enabled device or sticker for the second time, then your phone will ask you whether you would want to add the app to the NFC trusted list or not.

Source: http://wmpoweruser.com/wp-8-1-has-fixed-the-biggest-problem-with-nfc-on-windows-phone/

Comment: Doesn't show up for me when I purchase something in the supermarket using SEQR. :/

Comment: Have you tried making your payment more than once with the same app?

Comment: Yes, though probably I've paid at different payment terminals. Each terminal got a different NFC sticker.

Answer (score 0):

As toydenrego said, for normal apps you can just add an app to your trusted apps and it will not ask again the next time.

However, I highly suspect this is not possible when there's a payment involved. I wasn't able to find any documentation or official info on this, but I bet this is by design to prevent people stealing your money without you knowing.

Comment: I always have to enter a PIN in the SEQR app so it's not possible to steal money by tapping it somewhere.